# Does a solar panel encased in glass give off less power?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, speed-of-light

The speed of light in glass is about 2/3 c.   If we encase a solar panel in glass, does it give off less power because of this reduced speed of light? (and ignoring other things like the reflectivity of glass, etc.)

Comment: The glass may absorb or reflect some of the incident radiation, but the reduced speed of light in a material does not change the photon energy.

Comment: What do you mean by "increase a solar panel in glass" ?

Comment: @BrendanDarrer  Sorry for my bad spelling. I said incase. Should be encase.

Answer (score 1):

No, there would be no change in the amount of generated power.

The situation you describe would not change the rate that photons are arriving at the surface of the solar cell. Assuming we aren't worried about angular dependence or changes in reflection, photons would be converted into usable power at the same rate.